# No module named openmdao.api

Tags: openmdao

After I installed openmdao following the getting started page manual: pip install 'openmdao[all]', and try test the example by python paraboloid_min.py, why it returns that No module named openmdao.api ?? Anyone could help, thank you very much!

I tried:
pip install 'openmdao[all]'
python paraboloid_min.py

And I expect:
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
Current function value: -27.333333333333336
Iterations: 5
Function evaluations: 6
Gradient evaluations: 5
Optimization Complete

Comment: this is what it returns: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "paraboloid_min.py", line 1, in <module>
    import openmdao.api as om
ImportError: No module named openmdao.api

Comment: It seems like OpenMDAO has been installed into a python environment different from the one used to run the script.

I suggest trying `python -m pip install openmdao[all]` and then running the script using `python paraboloid_min.py`.  That should ensure the same environment is being used in both cases.